# 'setExact' method of AlarmManager not behaving correctly

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm working on a CountDown app. I want to launch a 'end of countdown activity' when the countdown reaches 0. I have a variable keeping track of how much time is left (variable that I use to display the countdown).

The documentation gives me this (I have to use this method because it's part of the exercise):
`public void setExact (int type,long triggerAtMillis,PendingIntent operation)`

Knowing this I pass my *countdown variable* as the second argument thinking the activity would roughly be opened around the time I've given.

Let's say, I put a duration of 30s in the *duration variable*. I start the countdown by pushing a button and I use the 'setExact' method using the *duration variable*.

Even though, I pass 30s (obviously converted in millis), the 'end of countdown activity' launches only after 5s.

Feel free to download [the project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ea_w5UA_HpPlIN2aWRb5dQ8V-bwTPQv/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please put the project into code inside of your question with 4 space indents.

Comment: Please don't just link to your project off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be passing in 30000 for the trigger time, when it should probably be 30000 plus the current time in ms.

From the documentation: 
triggerAtMillis long: time in milliseconds that the alarm should go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).